# how to show different color dots / bubbles in map?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a chart which is show below [image]

So I google it and found one example from this site 
http://jqvmap.com/
I am able to make a chart or map .but I have one issue I want to display bubbles in my chart or map as shown in image **(red and green or orange bubble)** can we show this bubble in map ?
can I use different library ? or Is there any way to add bubbles in this plugin

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/v4pb0FTTwGLrgP8akC6H?p=preview

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
          <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ysjcoz5ags6r0dh/jquery.vmap.js?dl=0"></script>

    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/l9jswedham3iiex/jquery.vmap.usa.js?dl=0"></script>


  </head>

  <body>
<div id="vmap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

  </body>
<script>
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'usa_en',
    backgroundColor: null,
    color: '#eeeeee',
    hoverColor: '#999999',
    selectedColor: '#666666',
    enableZoom: true,
    showTooltip: true,
    selectedRegions: ['MO', 'FL', 'OR']
});
</script>
</html>
```

I am able to show selected region .Selected background region is dark gray .I need to display bubbles instead to background color .

any update

Comment: planker link not working

Comment: it is working please check again..http://plnkr.co/edit/v4pb0FTTwGLrgP8akC6H?p=preview

Comment: you can use datamaps library https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/README.md#getting-started